# How to avoid the LazyInitializationException when submitting a form in JSF?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I've a many to many relationship between some entities. I'm trying to update the object from an edit page, but when I click the submit button (I'm using a jsf's commandLinkbut but the method that's referenced from the action atrribute is empty inside ) Hibernate is giving me a Lazy Initialization Exception.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

The work flow is the following: I list all the objects on a table and then click on a specific one to edit it (it takes me to another page). I fetch all the object with the method `getAllCases()` from the service that calls the method `getAllCases` from the DAO that uses the method `findByAll` from the HibernateGenericDAO.

Here is the main entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Case implements Serializable, commons.entities.Entity<Long> {

private List<Product> products;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "join_table",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
      uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"CASE_ID", "PRODUCT_ID"})}
  )
  public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
  }

  public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
  }
```

And here's the Product entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Product implements Serializable, commons.entities.Entity<Long> {

  private Long id;
  private String productName;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRODUCTS_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "CASE_PRODUCTS_seq", sequenceName = "PRODUCTS_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Column(name = "product_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
  }

  public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
  }
```

This is the service

```
@Component
@Transactional(
    propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
    rollbackFor = {
        RuntimeException.class,
        Exception.class,
        UnexpectedRollbackException.class
    })
public class CasesService {

  @Autowired
  public CasesService(ICaseDAO caseDAO) {
    this.caseDAO = caseDAO;
  }

 public void saveCase(Case case) {
    caseDAO.saveCase(case);
  }
```

This is the DAO

```
@Component
public class CaseDAO extends HibernateGenericDAO<Long, Case> implements ICaseDAO {

@Override
  public List<Case> getAllCases() {
    return this.findByAll();
  }

@Override
  public void saveCase(Case case) {
    this.merge(case);
  }
}
```

Comment: You will have to refetch(refresh) the entity because it was fetched in a different(previous) transaction.

Comment: Isn't there are more elegant solution?

Comment: @Priyesh: or do a merge...

Comment: @ericgramirez Remember to tag the person you would like to reply to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try activating the [hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans configuration property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-database-fetch).

But it would be better to have DTO objects initialized with all data required for the current user interaction.

Take the hint of the setting serious:

> Initialize Lazy Proxies or Collections outside a given Transactional Persistence Context.
>
> Although enabling this configuration can make `LazyInitializationException` go away, it’s better to use a fetch plan
>   that guarantees that all properties are properly initialized before
>   the Session is closed.
>
> In reality, you shouldn’t probably enable this setting anyway.

In general the settings (when `true`) enhances the lazy loading mechanism so that it will create a new TX->fetch->commit cycle on each lazy initialization if the original `Session` the entity was fetched in is already `closed`.

Comment: What about 'just' doing a merge when you know the entity is needed again?

Comment: @ericgramirez I cited that, yes.

Comment: @Selaron Isn't there another solution?